# How can I encode some input in a view when the view is posted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a C# MVC 5 internet application where a user enters XML input into a textbox in a view.

How can I encode this XML input as JSON when the view is posted?

Here is an example of the input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("data")
    </div>
</div>
```

Should the code to encode the value of the model.data input be in a javaScript onclick function, or somewhere else?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ data: values });` ?

Comment: xml2json looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Comment: @DavidPine: Where should the JSON.stringify({ data: values }) code be placed in the view?

Comment: @user3736648, you are you doing a form post from the MVC view?

Comment: Yes, with a <input type="submit"> button.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196645/post-json-data-through-a-form-in-mvc4